# Deploy Azure Function with an Alpine - Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, azure-functions-core-tools

I want to deploy Azure function (node and/or python) from the lightest DockerFile.

So I need to be able to run `az login` and `func`.

For now the only one which work well is 2.27GB.

---

I tried a lot of possibilities with alpines, but calling `func` always fails.

Examples :

- 1. [Fails] Alpine Latest - Install CLI from pip and func from NPM (**1.36GB**)

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN \
  apk update && \
  apk add bash make py3-pip && \
  apk add --virtual=build gcc libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev python3-dev make && \
  pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U pip && \
  pip3 install azure-cli && \
  apk del --purge build

RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm && \
    npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@latest --unsafe-perm true
```

Error is when I call `func -h` :

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/func ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/func',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/func',
  spawnargs: [ '-h' ]
}
```

- 2. [Fails] Node (12 or 14) alpine - Install CLI from pip and func from NPM (**1.55GB**)

```
FROM node:12-alpine # or 14-alpine

RUN \
  apk update && \
  apk add bash make py3-pip && \
  apk add --virtual=build gcc libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev python3-dev make && \
  pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U pip && \
  pip3 install azure-cli && \
  apk del --purge build

RUN npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true
```

Same error as alpine

- 3. [Success] node:12 / apt installation (**2.27GB**) :

```
FROM node:12

# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        lsb-release \
        apt-transport-https \
        gnupg \
        ssh \
    && apt-get clean

# Install azure function
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg \
    && mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs)-prod $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/$(lsb_release -rs | cut -d'.' -f 1)/prod $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

#Install Azure CLI
RUN curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg > /dev/null
RUN AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y azure-functions-core-tools \
    && apt-get install azure-cli
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest `azure-cli` [docker image](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/Dockerfile) is built with Alpine.
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to also run `azure-functions-core-tools` on Alpine... (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1358)

However, I managed to make a slightly "smaller" image starting from `ubuntu:20.04`

Size **1.77GB**, running in Gitlab CI without problems (the image is also published in our Gitlab, so the pull is pretty fast)

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg

RUN curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
RUN AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-$AZ_REPO-prod $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y azure-cli azure-functions-core-tools-3

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash && apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
```

Comment: do you realize extra tool "azure cli" need work with func cli together, which make the image huge

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to make it work independent of the size, here is a solution using the official Microsoft image, which ends up being 2.81 GB. Based on [this issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1358#issuecomment-500014603) I was able to make it work. However, it needed some modifications. Here is what I ended up with:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0.12493-python3.6-buildenv

# Install azure-cli
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install azure-cli

# Install azure-functions-core-tools
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev cargo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
RUN AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) && \
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list && \
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-$AZ_REPO-prod $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y azure-functions-core-tools-3
```

You can use this directly locally, but I needed it for the GitLab CI pipeline. So first you need to build and push the image to the GitLab Container Repository:

```
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/GROUP/PROJECT/REPO/container-name .
docker push registry.gitlab.com/GROUP/PROJECT/REPO/container-name:latest
```

And finally use it in the GitLab CI pipeline:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml
deploy:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/GROUP/PROJECT/REPO/container-name:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - dockerbuild-machine
  script:
    - pip3 install --target=".python_packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages" -r requirements.txt
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - az account set --subscription $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    - func azure functionapp publish $FUNCTION_APP --no-build
```

Comment: thanks, this image is 2.9GB already. But when using this image, to publish a dotnet function, i got this error `dotnet sdk is required for dotnet based functions. Please install https://microsoft.com/net`